# How to fix "fatal: unable to look up gitlab.f5net.com (port 9418) (Name or service not known)" with go get command

Tags: git, gitlab

Go version: 1.19.4

```
> go get gitlab.f5net.com/mbip/containers/f5-log-lib.git
gitlab.f5net.com/mbip/containers/f5-log-lib.git@v1.9.0: verifying module: gitlab.f5net.com/mbip/containers/f5-log-lib.git@v1.9.0: reading https://sum.golang.org/lookup/gitlab.f5net.com/mbip/containers/f5-log-lib.git@v1.9.0: 404 Not Found
        server response:
        not found: gitlab.f5net.com/mbip/containers/f5-log-lib.git@v1.9.0: invalid version: git ls-remote -q origin in /tmp/gopath/pkg/mod/cache/vcs/85832f3b5e37de5b7674a445589d879c8532f6953ca17bb7e76f2474d56e84e0: exit status 128:
                fatal: unable to look up gitlab.f5net.com (port 9418) (Name or service not known)
```

I tried running this command, I expected it to import the package, but got this error. I have used this exact command in a different repo and it worked, so I'm not sure why it isn't working here.

Comment: That's an error from your name server: Go reads the module, translates that to a place to attempt to `git clone` from or similar, then either runs Git or uses its built-in Git (there's a variant written in Go). But at that point whatever software wants to contact a server *at* `gitlab.f5net.com` has to *look up the name* `gitlab.f5net.com` to get an IP (v4 or v6) address, and the lookup step is failing. That's not a programming issue, it's a network operations issue.

Comment: And after you get the problem with the hostname fixed, then: package names are not git repositories. They don't have the suffix `.git` - remove that from the importpath that you're using with "go get"

Answer (score 0):

I found the solution. The repository is actually a private repo, which requires the GOPRIVATE environment variable to be set to the URL of that repo. Which would be `export GOPRIVATE="gitlab.f5net.com/mbip/containers/f5-log-lib.git"`